# Reload div in angular2

Tags: html, angular

Im calling an api in my html component. But I need to refresh it each time to be able to see the data.

html component:

```
<div>
<div *ngIf="reloadiv" class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1353px; height: 595px;'>
<object class='tableauViz' width='1353' height='595' style='display:none;'>
<param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fmbi-tab.abc.com%2F' />
<param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;IT' />
<param name='name' value='TPO&#47;ModelOutputMMX' /><param name='tabs' value='no' />
<param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='showShareOptions' value='true' />
</object></div>

</div>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
selector: 'model1',
styleUrls: ['./model1.scss'],
templateUrl: './model1.html'
})


export class model1 implements OnInit {
private reloadiv: boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
console.log("Init invoked");
this.reloadiv = true;
}

}
```

How do I reload div without refreshing the entire page?

Comment: Hey, If your end game is to just see the updated data in your template you can use ChangeDetectorRef from @angular/core

Comment: Why do you need to refresh it to see the data? What is your requirement here?

Answer (score 2):

In order to update the template with the latest data, first import ChangeDetectorRef

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
```

initialize it in your constructor

```
constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

and in the success part of your API call subscribe, once you've updated your variables, manually trigger template change detection with

```
  this.cd.detectChanges();
```

This should do the trick if because of any reason your change detection is not occuring automatically.